# How to click on a link on the basis of a custom attribute of <a> using codeception?

Tags: php, codeception

I am writing test case using CodeCeption in drupal.

The HTML of the link is this:

```
<a href="#" rule_id="83" class="delete-rule">delete</a>
```

I want to click on this link based on this rule_id. I'll provide the rule_id to it and it will click on the corresponding delete button.

I've tried to explore something like this but not succeeded yet.
Is there any way to click on this basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPath as argument of click() method. This should work for your example:

```
$I->click('//a[@rule_id=83]');
```

More examples you can find in Codeception docs: http://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests#PHP-Browser